# problems getting pygame to work on python 2.7 and 3

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, pygame

I've recently installed python 2.7 and 3 on my mac (running OSX Snow Leopard). I also tried installing pygame, however whenever i try importing pygame in either 2.7 or 3 i keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

I know a version of pygame has been installed successfully because when I use version 2.5 of python i'm able to import it fine. Does anyone know how i could link the pygame library to the other versions?

Also when i run this:

```
import struct; print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))
```

32 is returned for version 2.5, but 64 is returned for version 3.2. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are different packages for each version of python.  Go install the package for python 2.7.  http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

note that pygame isn't supported on 64bit yet

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo pip install pygame` or `sudo easy_install pygame` to install.
Pygame doesn't work on python 3.